# System Monitor fails to start - unable to find default local file monitor type

Tags: 18.04, system-monitor

Ubuntu 18.04 - System monitor fails to start.

Launching `gnome-system-monitor` from the terminal produces the following error:

```
(gnome-system-monitor:17633): glibmm-CRITICAL **: 09:35:39.143: 
unhandled exception (type Glib::Error) in signal handler:
domain: g-io-error-quark
code  : 0
what  : Unable to find default local file monitor type
```

I have tried reinstalling with:

```
snap remove gnome-system-monitor
sudo snap install gnome-system-monitor
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ killall gnome-screensaver
```

I do not know why,but it works! There are too many gnome-screensaver in `ps aux`.

See bug report on launchpad: [Unable to launch gnome-system-monitor](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+bug/1430068)

Comment: I get "gnome-screensaver: no process found"